# Adding text to a bound TextBlock

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textblock

I would like to prepend a text in a data-bound text block:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

The text that is shown is:

```
"My title"
```

What I want to be shown is:

```
This is "My title"
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property of the binding:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat=This is {0}}"></TextBlock>
```

Check out this blog post for more information: [WPF String.Format in XAML with the StringFormat attribute](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/).

Comment: This didnt work for me when my string was `{0} Complete` I had to use the answer below `{}{0} Complete`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to do it in the binding:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Title">
            <Binding.StringFormat>
                This is "{0}"
            </Binding.StringFormat>
        </Binding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Element syntax required to escape quotes. If the quotes where just to mark the inserted text and should not appear in the output it is much easier of course:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, StringFormat={}This is {0}}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28">
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do this with a converter.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, ConverterParameter=This is, Converter={StaticResource TextPrefixConverter}}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
```

The converter would simply prefix the bound value with the ConverterParameter.

```
public class TextPrefixConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {                        
        String result = String.Empty;
        if ( parameter != null)
            result = parameter.ToString( );

        if (value != null)
            result += value.ToString( );

        return result;
    }
...
}
```

It's not obvious is the spaces and/or quotes are intended to be part of the output.  If so, the converter could be changed to trim the spaces and/or add quotes to the constructed string.

Another way of doing this is:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" >
    <Run Text="This is " />
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />       
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi You can write as following:

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBlock>This is </TextBlock>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

just use StringFormat for formatting purpose.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title,StringFormat='This is {0}'}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach here in terms of **performance**, as already answered, is using `StringFormat` for `Binding` and assign it to the `Text` property of `TextBlock`.

However if performance isn't a concern, and XAML readability is preferred, another approach is to use `Run` inside `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28">
    This is <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Also, this way you can apply different styles (text/background color, italic/bold font, font size, etc.) to different parts of your `TextBlock`, which is something you can't do with `Binding`'s `StringFormat`. And this is way more efficient than having multiple `TextBlock`s with different text/background styles.